# How to debug .NET dll using mono from native C++ project

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mono

I have a native C++ project which uses .NET managed dll by mono. I cannot debug .NET managed dll variables through visual studio debugger. Is there a way to debug my dlls?
Thank you for your time...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You have a native C++ project that uses a .NET DLL you compiled in Mono? And you want to use Visual Studio 2010 to debug *both* of these projects at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug .NET managed dll then of course, you need to start your c++ project executable from .NET managed dll source code. In .Net Dll's project properties, in Debug tab select "start external program" as start action and browse the C++ application. and set the working directory as same directory path.

Now you can debug your code by pressing F5.

Thanks,
Regards,
Robo

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to easily debug managed (C#) code in Visual Studio that is run with mono. You can debug the C/C++ code of your app in Visual Studio, including the mono runtime. To debug the managed pieces of your code, see this post:

[Debugging C# assembly launched by embedded mono runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649503/debugging-c-assembly-launched-by-embedded-mono-runtime)